# NMinimize with four equations for four points

Tags: equation-solving

The following is an unsuccessful attempt to pass a parabola through four points.

```
f[x_, y_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := y - (a x + b + Sqrt[c x + d])
NMinimize[
  {1, f[3, 0, a, b, c, d] == 0, f[-3, 0, a, b, c, d] == 0, 
  f[0, 4, a, b, c, d] == 0, f[0, -2, a, b, c, d] == 0}, 
  {a, b, c, d}]

{a = -0.2806802780648826`, b = -0.47569478897971074`, 
 c = 0.44278812103135534`, d = 1.326785837418332`};

ContourPlot[f[x, y, a, b, c, d] == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 5}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic]
```

`NMinimize` does not seem to work here. Is there a work-around?

[image]

Comment: `f[x_, y_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := y - (a x + b + Sqrt[c x + d]) ; min =   NMinimize[{1, f[3, 0, a, b, c, d] == 0, f[-3, 0, a, b, c, d] == 0,     f[0, 4, a, b, c, d] == 0, f[0, -2, a, b, c, d] == 0}, {a, b, c,     d}]; {f[3, 0, a, b, c, d] == 0, f[-3, 0, a, b, c, d] == 0,    f[0, 4, a, b, c, d] == 0, f[0, -2, a, b, c, d] == 0} /. Last[min] `return  `False`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the math is amiss (the equation is wrong for a tilted parabola).

Comment: One plausible reformulation: `conic[x_, y_] := a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + 1
polys = {b^2 - 4*a*c, conic[3, 0], conic[-3, 0], conic[0, 4], 
   conic[0, -2]};
Solve[polys == 0]

Out[393]= {{a -> -(1/9), b -> -(1/(3 Sqrt[2])), c -> -(1/8), d -> 0,   e -> 1/4}, {a -> -(1/9), b -> 1/(3 Sqrt[2]), c -> -(1/8), d -> 0,   e -> 1/4}}`

Answer (score 3):

**modified answer**

Try `NMinimize` (after correction of your equations…)
f[x_, y_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := y - (a x + b + Sqrt[c x + d])
NMinimize[{1, f[3, 0, a, b, c, d] == 0, f[-3, 0, a, b, c, d] == 0,f[0, 4, a, b, c, d] == 0, f[0, -2, a, b, c, d] == 0}, {a, b, c, d}]

```
(*{1., {a -> -0.28068, b -> -0.475695, c -> 0.442788, d -> 1.32679}}*)
```

Unfortunately NMinimize gives an error message `NMinimize::nosat: Obtained solution does not satisfy the following constraints within Tolerance -> 0.001 : {2+b+Sqrt[d]==0,-4+b+Sqrt[d]==0,-3 a+b+Sqrt[-3 c+d]==0,3 a+b+Sqrt[3 c+d]==0}.`
That means, no real solution exists for your ansatz `f`!

**Reading your question again you try to find a conic section (perhaps a parabola) through four points `{{3, 0, 0}, {-3, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {0, 4, 0}}`?**

If yes try

```
xyz= {{3, 0, 0}, {-3, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {0, 4, 0}}
Q = {1, a, b, c, d, e}.{1, x, y, x^2, x y, y^2}; (*conic section*)
elli = NonlinearModelFit[xyz , {1, a, b, c, d, e}.{1, x, y , x^2, x y, y^2} ,{a, b, c, d,e}, {x, y}]
```

parabola follows with an additional constraint `Det[D[Q, {{x, y}, 2}]] == 0`

```
para = NonlinearModelFit[xyz, {Q, Det[D[Q, {{x, y}, 2}]] == 0}, {a, b, c, d, e}, {x, y},Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

plot results:

```
Show[{ContourPlot[{0 ==  elli[x, y], 0 == para[x, y]}  , {x, -5,5}, {y, -5, 5}], Graphics[Point[xyz[[All, {1, 2}]]]]}]
```

Plot shows two possible solutions via conic section!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, changed code as you suggested. Not passing through any point, some new tweaking needed?

Comment: @Narasimham Your equations have no real solution `a,b,c,d` I think.

Comment: @Narasimham Look at my modified answer, which show a conic section through four points.

Comment: Five points in a plane determine a conic section $ ax^2 + 2h xy+...=0$. When  vanishing determinant $a b-h^2$ is plugged in any four points determine two arms of  planar parabola $y=f(x) = a x+b \pm \sqrt{cd+d}$ separated by the point of vertical tangency or infinite slope.

Comment: @Narasimham Might be true, but you only considered one branch in your question(which has no real solution). And my answer shows a possible real solution in form of an ellipsoid.

Answer (score 2):

The four points you specify result in the following equations:

```
{-3 a - b - Sqrt[3 c + d] == 0, 3 a - b - Sqrt[-3 c + d] == 0, 
 4 - b - Sqrt[d] == 0, -2 - b - Sqrt[d] == 0}
```

Looking at the last 2 equations:

{4 - b - Sqrt[d] == 0, -2 - b - Sqrt[d] == 0 }

we we see that this claims:

{4  - Sqrt[d] == 0, -2 - Sqrt[d] == 0 }

But this is obviously a contradiction. So, your equations can not have a solution.

Furthermore, the model you try to fit, is: `y==a x + b + Sqrt[c x + d]`, but I think this is not an equation of a parabola.

Answer (score 1):

We set `z==y - (a x + b + Sqrt[c x + d])` and the equation become `d + c*x == (y - z - b - a*x)^2`

```
sol = Solve[{d + c*x == (y - z - b - a*x)^2 /. {x -> 3, y -> 0}, 
   d + c*x == (y - z - b - a*x)^2 /. {x -> -3, y -> 0}, 
   d + c*x == (y - z - b - a*x)^2 /. {x -> 0, y -> 4}, 
   d + c*x == (y - z - b - a*x)^2 /. {x -> 0, y -> -2}}, {a, b, c, 
   d}]
eq1 = d + c*x == (y - z - b - a*x)^2 /. sol[[1]];
eq2 = d + c*x == (y - z - b - a*x)^2 /. sol[[2]];
ContourPlot[eq1 // Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
ContourPlot3D[eq2 // Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

$$9-\frac{4 \sqrt{2} x}{3}=\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2}
   x}{3}+y-1\right)^2$$

$$\frac{4 \sqrt{2} x}{3}+9=\left(-\frac{2 \sqrt{2} x}{3}+y-1\right)^2$$

Comment: aa = ContourPlot[eq1 // Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}];
bb = ContourPlot[eq2 // Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}];
Show[{aa, bb}, GridLines -> Automatic]                                                          
Added ( into my question) graphs of the last two 2D equations in your answer, Looking to the admissibility of both of them.

Comment: @Narasimham `NMinimize` return the wrong solution.

Comment: Why is it necessary to bring in  z  at all ?